# Yes/No :If $W_1 \oplus W_2 $ is a $T -$invariant subspace of a vector space $ V,$ then $W_1$ and $W_2$ are also T-invariant.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement true/false ?

> If  $W_1 \oplus W_2 $ is  a  $T -$invariant  subspace   of  a vector  space $ V,$ then $W_1$  and  $W_2$  are  also T-invariant.

**My attempt** : Actually , i don't  know  the  answer . However,  this statement is true  if $W_1=W_2$

let  $V= \mathbb{R}^2$  and $T(x,y)=(x+y,y+x)$.Let $W_1=W_2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :x+y=0\}$

$T(w_1+w_2)=T(w_1)+T(w_2) \in W_1 \oplus W_2$
$\implies W_1 \oplus W_2 $ is  a  $T -$invariant  subspace   of  a vector  space $ V$

$W_1$  and  $W_2$  are  also $T-$invariant.

Comment: If $W_1=W_2$ then this is a not a direct sum, unless the subspaces $W_1, W_2$ are trivial. Anyway, the statement is clearly false. You can find a counterexample in $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: okay @Mark I'm unable to find a counterexample. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Maybe think about it for more than 9 minutes?

Comment: By simple logic if you have transformation that maps $W_1$ to $W_2$ and $W_2$ to $W_1$ then if will preserve $W_1\oplus W_2$ but not individual spaces. For example consider $(x, y, z) \to (y, x, z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your example doesn't work since there is no internal direct sum $W_1\oplus W$ to speak of when $W_1=W_2$ (unless they are both the trivial subspace $\{0\}$).

Another idea pointed out in the comments, we could have $T$ swap $W_1,W_2$. For instance if use the coordinate axes $W_1=\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $W_2=\{(0,y)\mid y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ then $T(x,y):=(y,x)$ satisfies $T(W_1)=W_2$ and $T(W_2)=W_1$, so in particular $W_1\oplus W_2=\mathbb{R}^2$ (the whole space) is $T$-invariant. (Tony actually does this example in 3D.)

In this case, there *are* complementary (indeed, orthogonal) $T$-invariant 1D subspaces, they're just not $W_1,W_2$, instead they are the diagonal $D=\{(d,d)\mid d\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and "antidiagonal" $A=\{(a,-a)\mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}$. That is, we can say $D\oplus A$ is $T$-invariant with both $D$ and $A$ invariant. This doesn't always happen though (consider the last example I give momentarily).

Here's the reason we should **expect** the claim to be false: for *any* vector space $V$ and *any* subspace $W_1$, there is a complementary subspace $W_2$ for which $V=W_1\oplus W_2$. If it were true that $V$ being $T$-invariant forced $W_1$ and $W_2$ to be $T$-invariant, that would mean *every subspace* $W_1$ (of *any* dimension) of $V$ would also have to be invariant! Does that sound right? No, not at all; invariant subspaces can be more restricted than this.

For example, suppose $T$ is a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (by an angle not equivalent to $0^\circ$ or $180^\circ$... why?), and let $W_1,W_2$ be any two distinct 1D subspaces. What can you say in this case?